# PHP / MySQL Iterating through database to get counts

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP I'm iterating through a table using the following code:

```
// Alexandria

$a_total_sc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM offices WHERE hidden = '0' AND choice = '3' AND region = 'Alexandria'"));

$a_b_result_sc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM offices WHERE status = 'Behind'     AND hidden = '0' AND choice = '3' AND region = 'Alexandria' AND sales_code = 'A024'"));
$a_c_result_sc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM offices WHERE status = 'Completed'  AND hidden = '0' AND choice = '3' AND region = 'Alexandria' AND sales_code = 'A036'"));
$a_d_result_sc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM offices WHERE status = 'Delayed'    AND hidden = '0' AND choice = '3' AND region = 'Alexandria' AND sales_code = 'A049'"));
$a_o_result_sc = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM offices WHERE status = 'On Track'   AND hidden = '0' AND choice = '3' AND region = 'Alexandria' AND sales_code = 'A052'"));

// The only differences in the statements are the STATUS and SALES_CODE columns

$a_b_result_pct_sc = ($a_b_result_sc / $a_total_sc)*100;
$a_c_result_pct_sc = ($a_c_result_sc / $a_total_sc)*100;
$a_d_result_pct_sc = ($a_d_result_sc / $a_total_sc)*100;
$a_o_result_pct_sc = ($a_o_result_sc / $a_total_sc)*100;
```

I'm using `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc…` etc. to iterate through the data.

The problem is that I have over 700 offices to go through and just ONE of the offices takes more than a minute to process. That seems like a long time and I was trying to see if there was a faster way to get what I need -- which is BOTH the Number and the Percentage.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: You most likely could use just the one query here or a small subquery or aliasing. Make sure though that your table/database is properly indexed. It shouldn't take that much time to query.

Comment: The only index I have is on the `auto increment` ID column in the table. What other indices do you suggest?

Comment: It should be fine then. What is likely going on here that is slowing things down, is that you're using 2 functions all the time and querying over similar criterias. You could use a subquery as I said earlier, combination of `AND|OR` if needed also. Here's a tutorial link on subqueries http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/ if that will help. Edit: Or a CASE.